# Blank Actionbar on first Android app

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

This is my first android app and I'm trying to add the Actionbar at the top but i cant seem to get it to work. All I get is a Blank blue bar across the top with no title and no overflow menu. To create this i used the instructions found here http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html but even following the instructions to a T it doesn't seem to work. Even though I am not getting a compile error i was wondering if i was doing something wrong?

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.caseybowman.studdybuddy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        RelativeLayout main_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Semesters);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.add:
                //do something
                return true;
            case R.id.edit:
                return true;
            case R.id.settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.caseybowman.studdybuddy.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Semesters">

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```html
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.caseybowman.studdybuddy.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/Add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/Edit"
        app:showAsAction="IfRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/Settings"
        app:showAsAction="IfRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Or you can customize your toolbar by defining one TextView inside the toolbar and assign your title like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Your Title"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: using your code i was able to find out that It was working and I was too frustrated to notice i was looking at the wrong place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```